Spring Security - Unrestricted Access on Unauthenticated Endpoints in Custom Role-Based Authorization
I'm trying to configure Spring Security to restrict access to endpoints based on roles defined in my application.yml file. I have specified some open paths that should be publicly accessible, while other paths require specific roles. Despite this setup, I'm able to access unauthorized endpoints (e.g., /api/example) without any restrictions.
Here’s my setup:
1. Security Configuration:
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    return getHttpSecurity6v(http).build();
}

private HttpSecurity getHttpSecurity6v(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    return http.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
            .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> {
                // Permit all for open paths
                securityProperties.getOpenPaths().forEach(path -> auth.requestMatchers(path).permitAll());

                // Set role-based restrictions if roles are defined
                if (securityProperties.getRoles() != null) {
                    Map<String, Set<String>> pathRolesMap = securityProperties.generatePathRolesMap();
                    pathRolesMap.forEach((key, roles) -> {
                        String[] parts = key.split(" ", 2);
                        HttpMethod httpMethod = HttpMethod.valueOf(parts[0]);
                        String path = parts[1];
                        auth.requestMatchers(httpMethod, path).hasAnyAuthority(roles.toArray(new String[0]));
                    });
                }
                
                // Restrict all other requests
                auth.anyRequest().authenticated();
            })
            .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
            .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
            .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
}

2. Role Mapping Logic:
The generatePathRolesMap() method creates a map that associates HTTP methods and paths with required roles.
public Map<String, Set<String>> generatePathRolesMap() {
    Map<String, Set<String>> pathRolesMap = new HashMap<>();

    roles.forEach(role ->
            role.getEndpoints().forEach(endpoint ->
                    endpoint.getMethods().forEach(method -> {
                        String key = method + " " + endpoint.getPath();
                        pathRolesMap.computeIfAbsent(key, k -> new HashSet<>()).add("ROLE_" + role.getRole());
                    })
            )
    );

    return pathRolesMap;
}

3. Configuration in application.yml:
The configuration specifies open paths and role-based access to certain paths.
security:
  openPaths:
    - /api/auth/**
    - /public/**
  roles:
    - role: user
      endpoints:
        - path: /api/user/**
          methods: [ "GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE" ]
    
    - role: admin
      endpoints:
        - path: /api/admin/**
          methods: [ "GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE" ]


Despite this configuration, I'm able to access unauthorized endpoints, like /api/example, without authentication or proper roles. I expected that only the specified openPaths would be accessible without authentication, and all other endpoints would require specific roles or authentication.
What I’ve Tried:

Verified that auth.anyRequest().authenticated() is in place to
restrict all other requests.
Checked that JwtAuthenticationFilter is    working correctly by
validating JWT tokens for protected endpoints.
Ensured that the    role mappings are correctly generated by the
generatePathRolesMap () method.

What could be causing unrestricted access to unauthorized endpoints? How can I ensure that only the paths defined in openPaths are accessible without authentication, and all other paths are restricted based on the specified roles?
